# Using vscode causing "vscode-remote link" Windows dialog to repeatedly display

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I use the VSCode SSH extension to remote into my desktop computer. I had to re-install my local copy of VSCode on my Windows machine last week. Since then, I've been repeatedly getting the following prompt. It seems to appear whenever my terminal outputs a file name or URL:

> You'll need a new app to open this vscode-remote link
> [image: vscode-remote link warning]

I can't figure out how to prevent this dialog from appearing, or how to associate VSCode as being the
default application to handle `vscode-remote` links. I'm not sure if there is some setting in VSCode that is causing this dialog to be launched, or how these URLs should be handled.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment because of low reputation score, so I'll post my answer to user598549 here:

You can set `openAnalyzer: false` in your webpack config. It's in `module.exports` under `plugins`, you add `openAnalyzer: false` in `new webpackBundleAnalyzer.BundleAnalyzerPlugin({`  HERE  `})`.

Comment: Actually on this site, an answer is the correct place to put an answer.

Comment: Where and how can I access the "webpack config" that you're talking about?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the underlying cause of the pop-up was use of the `webpack-bundle-analyzer` node package, which was trying to get my browser to open a generated HTML file. I was able to turn this off by providing it the `openAnalyzer: false` option to the module.

However, I am still not sure how I can create an association for `vscode-remote` links if I did want the reports to open.

Comment: Hi, if you can explain, I'd like to know more about this solution. How do you set `openAnalyser: false`? Thanks